# How do i map object in array

Tags: javascript

I want to map the object in the array and access it through the row and col fields

I have the following object array:

```js
const arrayList = [
  {row: 0, col: 0, name:'Ankara'},
  {row: 0, col: 1, name:'Tokyo'},
  {row: 1, col: 0, name:'Munih'},
  {row: 1, col: 1, name:'Basel'},
]
```

I want to be able to access those elements with a nested array.

***For example:***

`arrayMapList[0][0] = {row:0,col:0, name:'Ankara'}`

***Then I use:***

`arrayMapList[0][0]`

***The following should output:***

`{row:0,col:0, name:'Ankara'}`

Comment: That isn’t a valid array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make nested arrays.

```js
const arrayList = [
  {row:0,col:0, name:'Ankara'},
  {row:0,col:1, name:'Tokyo'},
  {row:1,col:0, name:'Munih'},
  {row:1,col:1, name:'Basel'},
];

const arrayMapList = [];
arrayList.forEach(el => {
  if (!arrayMapList[el.row]) {
    arrayMapList[el.row] = [];
  }
  arrayMapList[el.row][el.col] = el;
});

console.log(arrayMapList[0][1]);
```

Comment: if(!arrayMapList[el.row]) arrayMapList[el.row] = []
make the code 2lines shorter and in my opinion easier to read

Comment: @code not sure what downvote you are talking about. But I think you code is wrong. arrayMapList[el.row]  = arrayMapList[el.row] ?? [] could be used instead

Comment: @Griffin I had a space typo in my comment. It should be `arrayMapList[el.row] ??= []`, which is much more compact than both solutions. (I posted an answer with that solution.)

Comment: @code Wow, that's a neat way to initialize variables I was not aware of. And I say that beats the if line THANKS I was not aware of that :) But I think your use of reduce just complicates things, more lines of code and reduce is less common than forEach.

Comment: @Griffin sure. I prefer using reduce though because it eliminates all the dependencies and makes it a more "pure" function. Call it opiniated, I guess.

Comment: @code I go back and forth on whether to use `reduce`. I think it's easier to see the logic when written like this.

Comment: @Griffin I don't see the need for the most compact form in code like this. The logic is easier to see with an `if`, and writing it like that will often just prompt more questions from newbies.

Answer (score 1):

Consider making your array into a 2D array. For example:

```
const arrayMapList = [
    ['Ankara', 'Tokyo'],
    ['Munih', 'Basel']
]

let row = 0;
let col = 0;
console.log("Row:" + row + " Col:" + col + " Name: ");//Row:0 Col:0 Name: 
console.log(arrayMapList[row][col]);//Ankara
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const arrayList = [
  {row:0,col:0, name:'Ankara'},
  {row:0,col:1, name:'Tokyo'},
  {row:1,col:0, name:'Munih'},
  {row:1,col:1, name:'Basel'},
];

const result = arrayList.reduce((prev, cur) => (
  (
    prev[cur.row] ??= [], // conditionally assign if it isn't previously defined
    prev[cur.row][cur.col] = cur // assign row and col
  ),
  prev
), []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: While this does work, I have no idea why you would want to use parenthesis like this when you could just as easily write a few lines. Is this idiomatic in some other community?

Comment: @Potter it seems more intuitive to me and more elegant. It eliminates curly braces to give the code a more compact/less chunky aspect. I mean if you wish you could just rewrite it with brackets. Your choice, your code style.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with map() method. Just like this:

```
arrayList = [
  {row:0,col:0, name:'Ankara'},
  {row:0,col:1, name:'Tokyo'},
  {row:1,col:0, name:'Munih'},
  {row:1,col:1, name:'Basel'},
];

const mappedArray = this.arrayList.map(x => ({row: x.row, col: x.col, x}));
```